# How can i load an assembly into the global scope in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to make the types of a .net assembly available to all future sessions from within the current session?

Example:

```
# session 1
# mydll contains type mynamespace.mytype
Add-Type -Path <mydll>
```

```
# session 2
$o = New-Object -TypeName <mynamespace.mytype>
```

I thought about modifying and reloading the powershell profile in the first session, but i hope that there is a better solution...

Comment: What's wrong with adding it to the profile?

Comment: To add some context:
i am writing scripts for build-definitions on an Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015. The scripts are running sequentially. I have multiple scripts that need the same types to be added, so i plan to load the types in a script that is running before the other scripts. However, it seems as the loaded types are not available to the other scripts. That is why i assume, that they are running in different sessions.

We have about 30 machines that are running the builds, all of them are discarded and rebuilt after each build.

Comment: I probably could add the commands to add the types in a powershell profile, but then i would have to re-image all of the 30 machines. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Just make the profile changes for the needed resources part of your image, for rebuilds or use Powershell DSC to make setting changes after the build.

Comment: I just noticed that the $profile script is always re-executed when a new session starts. That is not what i want because it means that the startup of all new sessions will be delayed. I thought that the profile is only executed once and somehow automagically applied to a global context.